# Wavelet transform written in opencl: seeing artifacts in image

Tags: opencl

I have written a forward wavelet transform in opencl.

Basic algorithm is to divide the image into tiles of 128x8; the two left columns and two right columns are treated as boundary columns.

Tile data is moved into local memory, transformed, and non-boundary columns are stored in destination.

I am seeing image artifacts at the horizontal boundary of the tiles, and I can't figure out what is causing them. They occur on the fourth and 124th column, i.e. the first and last even column not on the boundary.

This project is open source:

https://github.com/boxerab/roger

Dependencies: Visual Studio 2012, Intel OpenCL SDK and OpenCV

Comment: Usually when I see artifacts in OpenCL data it is because of an out of bounds access issue.  Make sure all your indexing is done properly.  Are you testing on a CPU or GPU?  If GPU, try an Intel CPU and see if the code crashes and that is a good sign of OOB.  What are the values of the boundary numbers?

Comment: Thanks, Austin. My source is an opencl image with CLK_ADDRESS_MIRRORED_REPEAT set in the sampler. So, out of bounds is fine for the input. For the local memory and output, I am pretty sure there are not OOB issues, but I will have to double-check.  I have tested on both intel CPU and AMD GPU, and I see the problem

Comment: The boundary numbers are from the image, but they are only partially transformed ( this is a convoluion type of problem), so not written to destination.

Comment: I guess the other thing to check is the output index if you are pretty sure everything is working like `getLocalId(0) < WIN_SIZE_X - BOUNDARY_X`, should it BOUNDARY_X*2?

Comment: Oops, you are using an offset of BOUNDARY_X on the low end, so BOUNDARY_X*2 doesn't make sense, what about <= WIN_SIZE_X - BOUNDARY_X

Comment: well, index goes from 0 to WIN_SIZE_X -1.  And there are two boundary columns on the right. So, a non boundary column satisfies  getLocalId(0) < WIN_SIZE_X - 2

Comment: Austin!!! Yes, you were right. It was an out of bound access on the local buffer.  Please move your comment to the answer category, and I will award you full marks :)

Comment: Woo hoo, glad it works!  Those things can be frustrating because 99% of the code works, except the boundaries :)

Comment: Yes. Thanks so much; I was really tearing my hair out on this one.

Comment: Austin - I just wanted to thank you again for your help on this one. Finding this bug was a real turning point in developing my kernel : it is now running faster than I thought possible on my old HD 7700. You rock!

Comment: Awesome!  You've helped lots of other folks, glad to help you out.

Comment: @Jacko Is the repository still available anywhere on Github ? The link is currently dead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when OpenCL returns unexpected answers on boundaries it is an Out-of-Bounds issues.  If the majority of the code works except on boundaries, check that the memory access in the kernel is correct.  Usually it is going to be something to do with: global offset + global id, local offset + local id, or a combination being larger than what was allocated.  Make sure the global and local worksize and offsets in the C/C++ code match the memory allocated, since this gets translated into global and local ids in the kernel.

Edit: Try running the code on a CPU device, as these are less forgiving of OOB and will (usually) cause a stack overflow or something similar.  GPU devices are very forgiving and will usually either use undefined, 0 (depending on compiler options), or some bizarre super huge value.