# Wavelet transform in C language or OpenCL

Tags: c, opencl, wavelet

I want to implement the wavelets transform for images in OpenCL but I don't know how to do. I'm a beginner in OpenCL, all I know is making a matrix addition like this:

```c
__kernel void matrix_add(__global float* output, __global float* input1, __global float* input2)
{
   output[get_global_id(0) + get_global_id(1) * get_global_size(0)] = input1[get_global_id(0) + get_global_id(1) * get_global_size(0)] + input2[get_global_id(0) + get_global_id(1) * get_global_size(0)];
}
```

It's easy for me because it's only adding different pixels.
If someone knows how to code wavelets transform in OpenCL 1.0 (because I'm using FPGA), I will be very grateful.

Comment: A quick google search got me this. https://www.fit.vut.cz/research/product/434/.en , check if it's useful. kernel code is available as a download in the above link.

Comment: There are also several [scholarly pubs](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6180318) on this topic, if you can access them.  Then there is [this SO question/answer with examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25536033/645128).

Comment: I have put a very concise C example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947469